# Photoswipe not working in Chrome or Default mobile browsers

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, photoswipe

Ok so I built this mobile site, got everything in place and after the launch I found out that PhotoSwipe does not work in Chrome or the default browser for my HTC Evo.  It works fine in the FF mobile browser.  I think I found the problem.  I am using jQuery 1.9.1 and Jquery Mobile 1.4.2.  Downgrading my jQuery is not an option at this point.  Has anyone else experienced this problem or have a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally tracked it down.  In the code-photoswipe-1.0.11.js file I had to replace...

```
$(thumbEls).live('click', function(e){
```

with...

```
$(thumbEls).on('click', function(e){
```

and...

```
if (oldDisplayValue === 'none'){
```

with...

```
if (oldDisplayValue === 'none' || oldDisplayValue === ''){
```

For some reason Chrome was returning '' for var oldDisplayValue.  This may not be the proper fix but it works fine for me now.